# DataGrid Multiple KeyBinding to same function, how to know which key i have pressed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, key-bindings

I have this xaml:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="a" Command="{Binding Path=Function}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1,Path=SelectedItem}"></KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Key="s" Command="{Binding Path=Function}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1,Path=SelectedItem}"></KeyBinding>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

When i select a row and press a or s i bind the selected item to KeyPressed. My problem is how can i know which key i have pressed ? (I want to bind key pressed and selected item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2 keybindings, it would be more clear to have 2 distinct commands :

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="a" Command="{Binding Path=ACommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1,Path=SelectedItem}"></KeyBinding>
    <KeyBinding Key="s" Command="{Binding Path=SCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1,Path=SelectedItem}"></KeyBinding>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes you're right, but is a mess if you have 20 keys with 20 different commands. This is why i want to use only one command.

Comment: Instead of having 20 commands, you will have 1 command with a big switch case inside :)

Comment: Yes, but this is what they want me to do :/. I have no choice.